# Why would this function be getting called twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dialog bot that asks for an email, in this function, at the end it appends a button into the chat. It only repeats this for the email function, but all others only rune once. What could be causing this?

**My Setup (email conditional)**

```
  if (email.length > 0 && email_confirmed == true) {
    $("#message").hide();
    send_msg(
      "One second, let me go check and see where your practicum is in the queue.",
      function() {
        send_msg(
          "It looks like your practicum will be graded by {{ DATE }}", function(){
          send_msg("If this seems too long we may be in a bit of a delay as our team grades all these by hand. ", function(){
            send_msg("If it is longer than 10 business days please post in our community as you may have submitted with another email address", function() {
            email_confirmed = false;
            $("#message").hide();
            $("#controls").append(
            '<button class="options one" value="certifications" type="button">My Certifications</button>'
            );
            })
          })
          })
        });
      }
```

The problem occurs when you click the button "my certifications". It calls this conditional

**My Certs conditional**

```
//If user has certification issues
if (b_val == 'certifications'){
    send_msg('Awesome! Did you know we have over 75,000 certified users?', function(){
    send_msg('Please select which area of the certification process you are having trouble with', function(){
        $("#controls").append(
        '<button class="options one" value="practicum" type="button">Practicum status</button>' +
        '<button class="options one" value="exams" type="button">Exam issues</button>' +
        '<button class="options one" value="badges" type="button">Badge problems</button>'
        );
    })
  })
}
```

**This is how I execute my clicks**

```
  // Pushes user's selected values as text chats
  $("#controls").on("click", ".options", function() {
    // Remove buttons on click
    $("#controls button.options").remove();
    var text = $(this).text();
    var b_val = $(this).val();

    // Set user's name in front of each message
    var userName = "<span class='username user-dialog dialog'> Me: </span>";
    var newMsg = text;

    var prevState = $("#conversation").html();
    if (prevState.length > 3) {
      prevState = prevState;
    }
    $("#conversation").html(
      prevState +
        "<div class='user-log'>" +
        "<span class='currentmsg user-dialog dialog' style='right:-40px; position:relative;'><span class='user-di-arrow'></span>" +
        newMsg +
        "</span> </div>"
    );
    // conditional codes
});
```

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x7e0dbzc/20/) as well. To see what I am experiencing follow these steps:

1. enter name
2. click my certifications
3. click practicum issues
4. enter email
5. click my certifications

EDIT: [here is a video of the problem](https://gyazo.com/82b84161c35b5e73d6e970d365136aa5)

Comment: What you mean it runs the email twice, I ran it and it worked fine.

Comment: When you click the my certifications link after submitting an email, it will run the 'my certifications' option twice. I'll add a gif to my post.

Comment: Please try removing code until you have the least amount that demonstrates the issue, and include that [mcve] in the question itself, not only on a third-party site.

Comment: @trincot really? Are you following the user path? I tried in every browser I have and it's still happening...

Comment: [minified jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1otmtpg3/)

Comment: From what I can tell, you're calling `$("#controls").on("click", ".options"...` every time the user enters a value (I put an alert before it) - so you're adding the handler multiple times.  You see this on "My Certifications" because you have "my certifications" twice in the steps.  If you continue with 'practicum status', you'll get that twice on the second time around as well (then 3rd time etc)... same for all the buttons.   Move the delegated event handler out so that it is only called once.

Comment: Am I still adding it multiple times even if I remove it on click everytime?

Comment: Try moving the large `$("#controls").on('click', '.options', function() {...});` block into `$(function() {...})` where it belongs. [The problem will go away](https://jsfiddle.net/x7e0dbzc/20/).

Comment: *"Am I still adding it multiple times even if I remove it on click everytime? "* - yes, of course.  The point of delegated events is that you only need to call them once.  If you want to call it multiple times (maybe it uses a variable and you don't want to refactor) then use `.off()` before the `.on`

Answer (score 0):

In your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x7e0dbzc/20/), you have

```
  if (email.length > 0 && email_confirmed == true) {
    $("#message").hide();
    send_msg(
      "One second, let me go check and see where your practicum is in the queue.",
      function() {
        send_msg(
          "It looks like your practicum will be graded by {{ DATE }}", function(){
          send_msg("If this seems too long we may be in a bit of a delay as our team grades all these by hand. ", function(){
            send_msg("If it is longer than 10 business days please post in our community as you may have submitted with another email address", function() {
            email_confirmed = false;
            $("#message").hide();
            **$("#controls").append(
            '<button class="options one" value="certifications" type="button">My Certifications</button>'
            );**
            })
          })
          })
        });
      }
```

After it is done asking, it calls

```
$("#controls").append(
                '<button class="options one" value="certifications" type="button">My Certifications</button>'
                );
```

so that in turn calls the same function twice. You want to remove. If you don't want it to go back and starting again.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I want the user to be able to go back to ask another question

Comment: @Hoder That wasn't the question. The question was why does it repeat while other just run once. If that is your next question. You should ask another question.

Comment: No that's what that append function does, it adds the button for the user to go back. But when I click said button it repeats that function.